# how to handle the error "HTTP Status 500 - Unable to do Single Sign On or Federation"

Tags: jmeter

i am using the govt site.
after correlation facing the issue as "HTTP Status 500 - Unable to do Single Sign On or Federation" facing this while replaying the script in Jmeter. suggest me how to handle this. your suggestion so valuable for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to load test application which uses [Federated identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity), most likely [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) .

It means you won't be able to record and replay your test scenario without performing advance correlation of dynamic parameters. Correlation stands for process of extracting the dynamic parameter from previous response using [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), saving it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and adding as a parameter to the next request so your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) should look like:

[image: JMeter SAML SSO Test Plan]

See [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites) article for detailed JMeter configuration of the extractors and variables.